# Can't bevel round cutouts in a cube

Tags: modifiers, bevel

This seems to be a pretty typical problem. But reading many threads did not yet help me to find a solution.

I want to model a supposedly simple object. Unfortunately, the attached image is magnified. I have no idea how to make the image smaller. Looking at a smaller image makes it easier to understand the form.

I first tried to subdivide a base cube and model the cutouts, but this was not very successful.

The closest I came was using a boolean. However, I am not able to bevel the borders of the cutouts, regardless of the order of the booleans. When applying the boolean the geometry does not look too bad, but I still can't bevel the borders of the cutout, neither using a modifier nor directly.

I attach two .blend files: one with the boolean present, and one with the boolean applied. The design sketches can be found as empties in the .blend file.

Edit: @Chris. Your proposal did not help. This was my first idea as well. But if you look at the resulting topology after applying the boolean does not look too bad. I added another screenshot.

[image: Topology after applying the boolean]

[image: StopTablet]

[.blend files](https://www.dropbox.com/t/9X8eGEBoPw2KR5OB)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clean topology with holes in a mesh with bevel modifier?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/180268/clean-topology-with-holes-in-a-mesh-with-bevel-modifier)

Comment: The topology shown in screenshot has a number of high count Ngons around the boolean cut. Ngons and some modifiers, particularly  subsurf do not play well together   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/124419/how-to-quickly-fix-or-avoid-the-n-gons-caused-by-boolean-operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened the first of the attached files, StopTablet2.blend... the *Bevel Modifier* was before the *Boolean Modifier* so I changed that. And voilà, the object was beveled. And even more after disabling *Clamp Overlap*.

In the second file StopTablet3.blend you've set *Limit Method* of the *Bevel Modifier* to *Weight*, but only the edges on the top have bevel weights assigned (you can see it by the blue color). If you give a bevel weight to the other edges you want to bevel it works, at least if you disable *Clamp Overlap* again. Or use a different *Limit Method* like you did in the other file.

[image: bevel weight]

Comment: I had tried that before. That is the reason, why the other edges were still marked. But this leads to shading issues, especially at the corners. Any idea, how to get rid of these? Here is an updated .blend file: https://www.dropbox.com/t/CydVzOCWlBUA3J80

Comment: The shading issues are usually caused by overlapping faces etc. The problem with your edges is, if you set the bevel width so high that the bevel will move over the next edge it results in bad geometry and shading issues. The _Clamp Overlap_ feature is there to prevent that, but this can lead to non-beveld edges in some parts. Since you are using _Weight_ as _Limit Method_, you can try to give problematic edges a lower _Bevel Weight_ like 0.5 instead of 1. Or you have to remove edges which are in danger to be overlapped by hitting X > Dissolve Edges.

Comment: And taking a closer look at your mesh I see that the geometry is worse than it seems at first glance. There are some overlapping or very close vertices. Maybe you should select all, then hit M > Merge By Distance > 0.0001 (not larger, because then you ruin your mesh). This deletes 12 vertices that caused problems. Oh and setting the curved edges to a bevel weight of 0.6 should be fine.